# How can I set Password Never Expires for current users only in Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

Hi I have several users in my Active Directory Users. However I can't go to each one and set Password never expires.

> So If possible how can I set this option for all current users only?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Password Expiration in active directory](http://superuser.com/questions/599351/password-expiration-in-active-directory)

Comment: @Karan thanks for the reply. However do that change the old accounts configuration or just applies to new ones?

Comment: AFAIK Group Policy settings in AD won't have an effect on existing accounts until users try to change or update their passwords.

Comment: So I can't prevent the expiration to happen automatic?

Comment: If you set the policy to never expires, I believe it will come into effect only for the next password the user sets. Any current passwords should be governed by your present password expiration policy.

Comment: Cool, it worked! @karan

Comment: Good to know. :)